# Secure logout: session termination

Tags: php, security, session

I've been reading the security issue on logging out from a website system written in PHP, using sessions.

My current code is:

```
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION["logged_in"])) {
    unset($_SESSION["logged_in"]);
    unset($_SESSION["ss_fprint"]);
    unset($_SESSION["alive"]);
    session_destroy();
    session_regenerate_id(true);
}
// NEW MODIFIED CODE
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION["logged_in"])) {

$_SESSION = array();

if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

session_destroy();

header("Location: ../index.php");
die();
} else {
header("Location: ../online.php");
die();
}
```

I use [this class](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/12194.html).

The code from the class should ensure and protect against hijacking and capture and fixation.

I have generated a session with this code from the above link, and I want to logout properly.

I tried `print_r()` out all `$_SESSION data`, and it was empty after I ran my logout code.

Is my logout secure enough?

OBS:: This system I'm making is not for some big company with a huge big mega need for security, but the basics should be implemented.

Comment: die() is usually used to indicate an error, I would use exit; instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks alright enough. i would change is replace all those unset() lines with just `$_SESSION = array();`

and check the [manual](http://sg3.php.net/session_destroy), it has a sample to clear your session cookies if you have them enabled.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  So basicly i can just use the code efrom your link, and if i have session cookies enabled they will get deleted?

Comment: I change my unset() with $_SESSION = array();

Comment: I modified my code in my original question.. any comments on it?